# Writing For Loops in Swift 3

Tags: loops, for-loop, swift3, xcode8

I am confused on how to write a for loop in Swift 3 when needing to use operators and user input.

```
    let userNum = Int(usernumInput.text!)

    for i in 1...<=userNum  {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            print(i)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're code is close, although it won't be able to loop over it because it's an Int value; only objects that conform to the SequenceType protocol can be used in a for ... in loop.

```
let userNum : Int? = Int(usernumInput.text!)

for i in 1...userNum! {
    print(i)
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        print("---")
    }
}
```

<sub>**Output**:</sub>

```
1
2
---
..
```

If you simply want to skip over every other iteration, try `stride` — it  works like this:

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: userNum!, by: 2)  {
    print(i)
}
```

<sub>**Output**:</sub>

```
0
2
4
..
```

Comment: Thanks everyone who responded! This is the answer that helped the most. Thank you so much! I now understand how to format loops in Swift 3. That being said, I do like the older style more though.

Comment: This solution has twice as much loop overhead than it needs. Don't  iterate over all numbers just to skip half of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let userInputText = usernumInput.text,
      let userInputInt = Int(userInputText) else {
    fatalError("Input text is nil or not a valid Int")
}

for i in stride(from: 1, to: 10, by: 2) {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer instead of providing only code.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. I've given enough information to point OP towards the right direction. They can easily find documentation on stride, guard, etc. I'll also answer any follow up questions. But SO is not an api reference search engine.

Comment: Generally answers are intended to be viewed by a wider audience than just the OP; no idea what your last sentence means.